# change asp.net image url with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to use jQuery to change an image every 15 seconds so this works in all browsers. I have tried removing this markup and leaving the div empty and using jQuery to change the background-image url>

How can the image url be changed with jQuery

Given this markup;

```
<div id="logotransitions" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle"
                           ImageUrl="~/Images/MainLogo_png_270x180.png" />
</div><!--logotransitions  -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<asp:Image>` should be rendered as an  tag. Hence you should be able to modify the `src` property.

```
$('#logotransitions > img').prop({ src: 'someimage.png' });
```

Comment: if i have three images in that div how can i put their url src's in an array becuase this doesn't work   var arrayOfImages = $('#logotransitions').find('img').map(function () {
                         return this.attr('src');
                }).get();

Comment: @dinotom Try changing `this.attr('src');` to `$(this).attr('src');`. You are trying to run a jQuery method on a dom element.

Comment: i tried to upvote you for this but trigger finger double clicked which resulted in upvote and recall of it and it wont let me do it again

Comment: @dinotom Are you referring to my last comment? Did it help you out? As long as it's working for you I'm happy ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can get the client side ID of the Image tag and change the source of the Image like below

```
$("#<%=Image1.ClientID%>").attr('src','http://image/url.jpg');
```

It will change the src attribute of the img tag

Comment: Year right.. you must add this code in the same file where your code resides. and also jquery should load before the function call