# Expanding a Refreshing Image in JS

Tags: javascript, html

**Quick background:** I've got an application that pulls an JPG from an IP camera and refreshes the image every half second to create a video feed.

**Goal:** I'm trying to make the image so that when clicked, it will popup larger - ultimately with a different z index but that's to come later.

**Problem:** When I add the following JS to my ImageID it has absolutely no affect on my image when clicked.

```
$(function ()
{
    $('Image1').on('click', function ()
    {
        $(this).width(1000);
    });
});
```

**The Rest:**

---

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" />
</div>
```

Here is my JS Refresh:

```
setInterval(function() {

    //Source for Warehouse 1
    var image1 = document.getElementById('Image1');
    image1.src = 'http://CAMERAIP/snap.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();

}, 500);
```

Comment: What made you tag this with [tag:classic-asp]???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery syntax, so make sure you have the jQuery library included somewhere on your page (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) for details).

<s>Furthermore you need to change from</s>

```
[...]
$('Image1').on('click', function ()
[...]
```

to

```
[...]
$('#Image1').on('click', function ()
[...]
```

You are selecting the element via its ID, so you've got to use the ID selector which is #[element ID]. You can read more about jQuery selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you are trying to select an asp Image, not an `<img>` tag. As your asp-Image is generated on server side the ID will not be the same for the generated HTML and my suggested selector will not work.

Instead, use `$("#<%=Image1.ClientID%>")`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16359572/4503776)

Comment: Thank you for noticing an issue I didn't know I had yet! The original issue... it helps to include libraries "correctly".

Comment: @CodyJ.Mathis, please see my edit. My answer yesterday was a bit of a quick shot, sorry for that ;)